# Subdivide an internal element horizontally or vertically with css grid and display contents

Tags: css, flexbox, display, css-grid

is there a way to subdivide space horizontally like in [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u93s7xdq/24/) in an internal element of the grid using the css grid and not the flexbox?

In the fiddle the first row uses flexbox and works fine but I'm wondering if I can use the grid columns to divide space in an internal element of the grid for the second row.

I've seen that `display: contents` does the magic but today is poorly supported.

Do I have to use the flexbox until `display: contents` will be supported enough?

If you are using a recent browser and changes the `display` propriety of the second grid's div to `display: contents` everything works fine.